# What is the meaning of $$$ in LaTex?

Tags: math-mode, equations

I want to know the meaning of the triple `$` in my document.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry} 
\geometry{top=1.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3cm, right=3cm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}


\begin{document}
\section*{Solucionario}
%\begin{multicols}{2} 
\begin{enumerate}

\item  $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{2} x^3-2x\:dx $ 
\begin{equation}
$$$
\notag \displaystyle\int_{-1}^{2} x^3\:dx-\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{2} 2x\:dx  \\ \\ \\
\notag \displaystyle \left. \frac{x^4}{4}\right|_{-1}^{2}-\left.\frac{2x^2}{2}\right|_{-1}^{2} \\ \\ \\ 
\notag \displaystyle \left. \frac{x^4}{4}\right|_{-1}^{2}-\left.x^2\right|_{-1}^{2}\\ \\ \\
\left(4-\frac{1}{4}\right)-(4-1)\\ \\ \\
\frac{15}{4}-3 \ = \ \textcolor{red}{\frac{3}{4}}
$$$
\end{equation}

\item $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} x^{4/5}\:dx $
\begin{equation}
$$$
\notag \displaystyle \left.\frac{x^{9/5}}{\frac{9}{5}}\right|_{0}^{1} \\ \\ \\
\notag \displaystyle \left.\frac{5x^{9/5}}{9}\right|_{0}^{1} \: = \: \textcolor{red}{\frac{5}{9}}
$$$
\end{equation}

\item $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \frac{4}{t^2+1}\:dt $
\begin{equation}
$$$
\notag 4\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{t^2+1}\:dt \\ \\ \\
\notag \left.4 \tan^{-1} t\:\right|_{0}^{1}\\ \\ 
\notag \textcolor{red}{180\: =\:\pi}
$$$
\end{equation}

\end{enumerate}
%\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your equations are very strange and `$$$` doesn't make sense at all. The question i am asking right now: Why do you use it, where did you find that?

Comment: I use that because ShareLatex show me an error when I use one or two $. Pd:The equations are the solution of an integral.

Comment: You shall not use one `$`, nor two `$`, nor three `$` in an `equation` environment.

Comment: @PlusCodeX: Use only `\begin{equation}`...`\end{equation}` *without* `$$$`.

Comment: What you are probably looking for is `gather*`.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of copying and pasting the code from the linked page to the body of your posting.

Comment: @Johannes_B - Or, "Thou shalt not ..." -- an Eleventh Commandment! :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B --- five is right out!

Comment: @IanThompson I was thinking exactly the same :)

Comment: So you made up your own symbol sequence in order to avoid an error, and now you are asking what your symbol means?

Comment: I've said it before and I'll say it again. Getting hands on and getting stuck in and learning by doing is a *great* way to learn LaTeX and it's very fulfilling and probably more immediately productive, and who wants to page through a long dry manual anyway? But you've got to get a decent introduction and learn the very basics before diving right on in there and when you want to use a new environment you should look up how to do so. At the very least, if you encounter a problem, don't just hack your way around it, but look up what the error means and how to solve it

Comment: Which is basically a long way of saying, please consider looking at [a good beginner's guide](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner), it will help in the long run! And by all means, get hands on, please, you don't need to read a manual cover to cover before you type your first backslash, but a little theory would go a long way

Comment: Thanks to everybody. I never thought that my question would be so popular. I am going to look a good beginner´s guide and practice a lot about the differents environments.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `$$$` directives appear to be there to cope with and work around some rather questionable coding practices embedded in your code. The instances of `$$$` occur in pairs. The first instance of each pair is interpreted by TeX as `$$` (end of displaymath mode that was initiated by the preceding `\begin{equation}` environment plus a line break) followed by `$` (start of inline math mode). The second instance is interpreted by TeX  as `$` (end of inline math mode) followed by `$$` (line break followed by start of displaymath mode, to be terminated later on, by the subsequent `\end{equation}` instruction). This method "works", but just barely, and requires the use of lots and lots of `\displaystyle` directives that clutter up the code.

Since you're using multi-line equations, you shouldn't be using `equation` environments to begin with. Instead, you should use `align*` environments along the lines shown in the following example. You should also get rid of the "`\:`"  and "`\`" spacing directives. (Use `\,` to offset the dummy variable of integration, not `\:`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry} 
\geometry{top=1.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, hmargin=3cm}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\section*{Solucionario}
\begin{enumerate}

\item  $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{2} x^3-2x\,dx $ 
\begin{align*}
&= \int_{-1}^{2} x^3\,dx-\int_{-1}^{2} 2x\,dx \\
&= \left. \frac{x^4}{4}\right|_{-1}^{2}-\left.\frac{2x^2}{2}\right|_{-1}^{2} \\ 
&= \left. \frac{x^4}{4}\right|_{-1}^{2}-\left.x^2\right|_{-1}^{2}\\ 
&= \left(4-\frac{1}{4}\right)-(4-1)\\
&= \frac{15}{4}-3 = \textcolor{red}{\frac{3}{4}}
\end{align*}

\item $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} x^{4/5}\,dx $
\begin{align*}
&= \left.\frac{x^{9/5}}{9/5}\right|_{0}^{1} \\
&= \left.\frac{5}{9}x^{9/5}\right|_{0}^{1} = 
   \textcolor{red}{\frac{5}{9}}
\end{align*}

\item $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \frac{4}{t^2+1}\,dt $
\begin{align*}
&= 4\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{t^2+1}\,dt \\
&= \left.4 \tan^{-1} t\:\right|_{0}^{1}\\
&= \textcolor{red}{180}=\textcolor{red}{\pi}
\end{align*}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Here's another attempt to fix up your code; note the use of top-aligned `aligned` environments to unify the multiline equations associated with each `\item`. If you need to allow page breaks inside the `aligned` environments, I suggest you add the instruction `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
  \geometry{top=1.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, hmargin=3cm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}
\section*{Solucionario}
\begin{enumerate}

\item  $\!\begin{aligned}[t]
&\int_{-1}^2 (x^3-2x)\,dx \\
&\quad= \int_{-1}^2 x^3\,dx -\int_{-1}^2 2x\,dx \\
&\quad= \frac{x^4}{4} \,\bigg\vert_{-1}^2
         -\frac{2x^2}{2} \,\bigg\vert_{-1}^2 \\
&\quad= \frac{1}{4}\,x^4 \,\big\vert_{-1}^2
         -x^2 \,\big\vert_{-1}^2\\
&\quad= \frac{1}{4}(16-1)-(4-1)\\[1ex]
&\quad= \frac{15}{4}-3 = \textcolor{red}{\frac{3}{4}}
\end{aligned}$

\item $\!\begin{aligned}[t]
&\int_0^1 x^{4/5}\,dx \\
&\quad= \frac{x^{9/5}}{9/5} \,\bigg\vert_0^1 \\
&\quad= \frac{5}{9}\,x^{9/5} \,\big\vert_0^1 =
   \textcolor{red}{\frac{5}{9}}
\end{aligned}$

\item $\!\begin{aligned}[t] 
&\int_0^1 \frac{4}{t^2+1}\,dt \\
&\quad= 4 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{t^2+1}\,dt \\
&\quad= 4 \tan^{-1} t \,\big\vert_0^1\\
&\quad= 4\,\frac{\pi}{4}=\textcolor{red}{\pi} = 180^\circ
\end{aligned}$

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Incidentally, I share @egreg's doubt that `180=\pi`. If you must show the non-radians term, please write `180^{\circ}`.

Answer (score 42):

The markup is completely wrong and should be removed, but to answer the question of what it means

```
\begin{equation}
$$$
\notag \displaystyle\int_{-1}^{2} x^3\:dx-\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{2} 2x\:dx  \\ \\ \\
\notag \displaystyle \left. \frac{x^4}{4}\right|_{-1}^{2}-\left.\frac{2x^2}{2}\right|_{-1}^{2} \\ \\ \\ 
\notag \displaystyle \left. \frac{x^4}{4}\right|_{-1}^{2}-\left.x^2\right|_{-1}^{2}\\ \\ \\
\left(4-\frac{1}{4}\right)-(4-1)\\ \\ \\
\frac{15}{4}-3 \ = \ \textcolor{red}{\frac{3}{4}}
$$$
\end{equation}
```

`\begin{equation}` starts a latex enviornment then does `$$` to start display math.

Then you have `$$` which ends display math with an empty display, but adding vertical space.

Then you have `$` which starts inline math which is why you need `\displaystyle` everywhere.

Then you have `$` which ends the inline math,

Then you have `$$` which starts another display math, adding vertical space.

Then you have `\end{equation}` which closes the empty display math, adding more spurious vertical space and closing the latex environment.